# Perl command line + add PATH before string in file

Tags: bash, solaris, perl

I want to add the PATH  - /usr/local/bin/perl   befpore string in the file by perl command line ( the perl command line must be in my bash script ) , I have solaris machine

the target to add - **/usr/local/bin/perl**  before the line **$APIDIR/scan.pl** in the file and after the char - **"**

please advice how to add the PATH - **/usr/local/bin/perl**  before  **$APIDIR/scan.pl** so finally I will get

the new line's -

```
      my $APIDIR="/usr/local/cp/api";           remark -  this line shouldn’t be change
      my $script="/usr/local/bin/perl   $APIDIR/scan.pl";
```

in place of

```
     my $APIDIR="/usr/local/cp/api";
     my $script="$APIDIR/scan.pl";
```

I try the following but its not change the line:

```
  [root@machine1a /var/tmp]#  perl -p -i -e 's/\/usr\/local\/bin\/perl \$APIDIR\/scan.pl/\$APIDIR\/scan.pl/g' file




  [root@machine1a /var/tmp]# more file
  my $APIDIR="/usr/local/cp/api";
  my $script="$APIDIR/scan.pl";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with sed e.g.

```
sed 's|$APIDIR/scan.pl| /usr/local/bin/perl   $APIDIR/scan.pl|' file >file.new
```

or with perl

```
perl -p -i -e  's|$APIDIR/scan.pl| /usr/local/bin/perl   $APIDIR/scan.pl|' file
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to replace $APIDIR with /usr/local/bin/perl $APIDIR ?  If so, your regex is backward.  You want something like:

```
s/\$APIDIR\/\/usr\/local\/bin\/perl $APIDIR/
```

So try:

```
perl -p -i -e 's#\$APIDIR#\/usr\/local\/bin\/perl \$APIDIR#g' file
```

I hope this is what you were after-

Comment: sorry but its not work -  perl -p -i -e 's/\$APIDIR//usr/local/bin/perl \$APIDIR/g' file
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/\$APIDIR//usr"
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "/bin/perl"
        (Missing operator before perl?)

Comment: My answer appears to have been modified during submission.  The "//" between $APDIR and usr should be replaced with "\/".

Comment: still the same problem - perl -p -i -e 's/\$APIDIR/\/usr/local/bin/perl \$APIDIR/g' file
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "/bin/perl"
        (Missing operator before perl?)
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "perl \"

Comment: You have slash in your string. Use other sparator. Example:
perl -p -i -e 's:\$APIDIR:/usr/local/bin/perl \$APIDIR:g' file

Comment: the target is to add the PATH only before $APIDIR/scan.pl - so its not good to add the PATH before $APIDIR because I have allot of string as $APIDIR in the file see my example ( I edit my quastion

Comment: @lain the target is to add the PATH before $APIDIR/scan.pl - so if we have in the file only the $APIDIR word so in this case no need to add the PATH !

Comment: use this: `perl -p -i -e 's#\$APIDIR/scan.pl#\/usr\/local\/bin\/perl \$APIDIR/scan.pl#g' file`

Comment: I already try it but this commsnd not add the PATH ,